# Saving a option field from a dynamic MySQL populated selectbox into another MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert a option from  a dynamic populated MySQL select box, into another table with other form variables. Please excuses all the newbie errors.

***This is the area of my form where the select box appears:***

```
<select class="form-control3" name="Select_Name" id="Select_Name">
    <?php include('../../controllers/controller1.php') ?>
</select>
```

***This is where it is declared in PHP:***

```
 $Select_Item1      = $_POST['Select_Item1'];
 $Select_Item2      = $_POST['Select_Item2'];
 $Select_Item3      = $_POST['Select_Item3'];
 $Select_Item4      = $_POST['Select_Item4'];
 $Select_Name       = $_POST['Select_Name'];

 $insert_movie      = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO ".$tbl_name." (Select_Item1, Select_Item2, Select_Item3, Select_Item4, Select_Name) VALUES ('". $Select_Item1."','". $Select_Item2."','". $Select_Item3."','". $Select_Item4."','".$Select_Name."')");
```

But when I submit the form, everything submits except the **$_POST['Select_Name'];**

Any help will be greatly valued. Thank you.

Comment: Could you, please, populate more code ?

Comment: @HAL9000 Hope this will solve it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you `echo $_POST['Select_Name']` and see what is its value? Maybe you are not doing it right in the  `<?php include('../../controllers/controller1.php') ?>`

Can I see what are you doing on you controller?
Also why dont you pass data from controller like a variable and do a foreach between the select command?

```
//codeigniter syntax

    <select class="form-control3" name="Select_Name" id="Select_Name">
        <?php foreach($var as $key):?>
            <option value="<?=$key?>"><?=$key?></option>//sth like this
        <? endforeach ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: @ Gunner Aziz. Thank you for your input. I have decided to go another route. And all works well now. I decided to rather have script picking the option from the select box, put it in another text input and capture that detail. Works beautiful! Thank you everyone once more!